# Oddity when declaring an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Basically I have something like this in my code

```
struct connComp {
  struct connComp *parent;
  struct connComp *neigh[noNN];
  int *pSpinValue, SpinValue, Flag;
  unsigned int size;
} comp[N];
```

and when I try to use the array of structures `comp[N]` as input to a function of the type `void function(struct connComp)` by writing `function(comp)` in my code, I receive the following error from gcc compiler:

> incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘function’ function(comp)
>
> expected ‘struct connComp’ but argument is of type ‘struct connComp *’

So it looks like `comp[N]` was declared as a pointer and I really cannot figure out why. Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Your function signature should be `void function(struct connComp[], size_t len)` and you could then call it as `function(comp, N)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array in C *is* a pointer. Specifically, to the first element of the array.

To pass a single element to your function, you need to specify which element that is. e.g.

```
function(comp[2]);
```

If you want to work on the entire array in your function, you need to change the function to accept an array of your struct, or a pointer to your struct. e.g.

```
void function(struct connComp[N]); /* to receive an array of a static size */
void function(struct connComp*);   /* to receive an array of a variable size */
```

Comment: As a further note, if you go with `void function(struct connComp*);`, you will probably need some way to indicate the size of the array. Either pass another parameter indicating size, or have some known value to indicate the last element.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand now, thank you very much!

Comment: *An array in C is a pointer.*  It's not that simple.  Try assigning something to an array - not an array element, such as `int x[10]; x = ...;`  Because an array is **not** a pointer.  A pointer is an lvalue that can be assigned to.  An unadorned array decays to the address of the first element.  That's not the same as an actual pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Passing pointers and arrays to a function and C is equivalent. `comp` is an array of N `connComp` structs. When you pass `comp` to the function you have the address of the start of the array, which behaves in the same way a pointer does. To use `comp` in a function that expects the struct, you have to dereference the pointer - try passing in `comp[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I'm a total n00b, as you can tell. So I should define the function as `void function(struct connComp *)`? I would like the function to take in input the whole array and not just the first element...is that possible?

Comment: An array is a pointer in C? `*comp` and `comp[0]` are the same thing. The error even says that the array he is passing in is a pointer.

Comment: @luca de finetti yes, if you want to use the whole array you can define the function as `void function(struct connComp *)`. However be careful about indexing -- it's often customary to have a second parameter for the length of the array.

Comment: @chux you are correct to say that they are not exactly the same thing, I edited my answer to reflect this to the best of my understanding, let me know if I'm still a bit off.

Comment: @WillReid Close enough.  OP is calling the function with `function(comp)`.  In this context, the _array_ `comp` is converted to the address and type of the first array element, a `struct connComp *`.